# Display longitude and latitude lines in CartoDb?

Tags: carto

I just started using CartoDb to develop some maps for my classroom.  I want to have it show longitude and latitude lines so I can give my students coordinates and have them plot them.  how do I set those to display?

Comment: You could update a shp file (or similar) of graticules and add it as a layer. Or you could add it to a WMS and choose your own source from the map back drop. I am not sure if you can show them any other way.

Answer (score 2):

Graticule files are available in the Natural Earth Data library, specifically [here](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-graticules/).

You can download the graticules you need and import the files to CartoDB directly.